# Is requestStart triggered on create, destroy and update or only on read?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to show **"Updating.."** message on update request starts.
and the `requestStart` function is not getting triggered.

Is `requestStart` triggered on all requests `(read, create, destroy and update)`?

It looks like it working only on read request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a support ticket and here's the response I got, apparently incomplete features can now be called "confusing". I'm going to remember to call all my bugs this from now on. ;-)

> Your observation is correct - by design the event fires only when the
>   read transport is invoked. This is a bit confusing for the user, which
>   is why we decided to change the behaviour and trigger requestStart for
>   each transport.
>
> This is logged as enhancement, however I cannot commit an exact
>   timeframe when it will be done. Please accept my apology for the
>   inconvenience caused.   Regards, Alexander Valchev